# How to get doc from firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to get a document from firebase and add it to Videoplayercontroller. But actually I dont know how .
Heres my code

```
      var firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
   firestore.collection('sendvideos').where("previewimage",isEqualTo: widget.videofile);
```

What im triying is getting the first the document from firebase where the previewimage field is equal to widget.videfile and then I wanna get from that document the videourl to add it to this

```
 controller = VideoPlayerController.network(video)
```

Hope anyone can help
heres my firebase [image]

So as you can see there is the preiviewimage field and I saved that value inside widget.videofile. And what I need

Comment: you should start by reading the doc, it may help, a lot, https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the document first:

```
 var videoCollectionQuery = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('sendvideos').where("previewimage",isEqualTo: widget.videofile).get(); 
//this will get all the documents that satisfy your 'where' condition, you need to use'get()' and 'await' also.
```

Then, after you got the documents, you can get for example the first one:

```
String videoUrl = videoCollectionQuery.docs.isNotEmpty ?videoCollectionQuery.docs[0].data()['videourl'] : 'No results found';
// this will get you the map you need, unless the query is empty, it'll return 'No results found'.
```

We need to understand how Firebase queries work. When we use the `where` clause, Firebase always returns a list of `docs`. Even if you know that only one single document exists in your Firebase, it'll still be returned in a list, which has one single item. But still to access this document, you need to use `docs[0]`. If no document satisfies your query, docs will be empty, and if you call `docs[0]` on an empty doc, it'll throw a null error.

That's why we checked if it's empty or not first, then used `docs[0].data()`.

Comment: yes that works im not really understand why you [0] but I printing the values and it seems to work

Comment: We need to understand how firebase queries work. When we use the `where` clause, firebase always returns a list of `docs`. Even if you know that only document exists in your firebase, it'll still be returned in a list, which has one single item. But still to access it, you need to use `docs[0]`. If no document satisfies your query, docs will be empty, and if you call index[0] on an empty doc, it'll throw an error. That's why we checked if it's empty or not first.

Comment: ok that make sense thanks maybe you can take a look on my 2. other questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67258353/how-to-play-a-video-from-firebase. and this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67257170/how-to-use-singlechildscrollview-correct-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

```
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();

  if (currentUser != null) {
    String uidCur = currentUser.uid;
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await Firestore.instance
        .collection("user_category")
        .document(uidCur)
        .collection('categories')
        .getDocuments();

    var x = querySnapshot.documents;

    _myCategoryData.clear();
    notifyListeners();
    x.forEach((f) => _myCategoryData.add(f));
```

MyCategoryData is a list